using a normalized formula from a book but not getting the correct values
I'm attempting a normalization formula (seen in the picture) but I'm not getting the result of 0 and 1. Instead I'm getting values greater than 1 and less than 0 (seen in the other picture).
I wrote the formula from the picture as =(E3-$V$3)/($W$3-$V$3).
E (last price)
V (MIN function of E)
W (Max function of E)
any help would be appreciated



I believe that your MAX and MIN values should include the latest values as well. If your MAX and MIN do not include those, then it is possible that $E3 > W3$ or $E3 < V3$, and your normalized value is above 1 and less than 0.
Currently what seems wrong (to me) is that the above step I mentioned is missing.

Thank you @KaiSqDist for the reply,                                                                                                  I apologize as I should have mentioned that the data starts at row 3, so E3, W3 and V3 are the latest values

Are W3 and V3 backwards looking?

Last value should be in the array.
Also in the formula you have "N" and "n", just a typo?

Thank you for your reply @achirikhin.
The formula is written like that in the book. the image is a screenshot of the page.                          Also, I don't understand your array comment. I believe V3 is in the parenthesis.
